# How to Show Specific Frames Seperately

Tags: python, video, frame

I would like to have specific frames from a live view and show them seperately on the screen.

My exact aim is to have the frames on the specific times. (1st at 3rd second 2nd at 5 second 11th is at the 10th second etc.) After that I will put them into image processing. These specific times, the device which I take the photos provides different lights properties and I will check the effect of these environmental changes.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a frame at a precise time is worth looking closely at the underlying requirements for, depending on the granularity you want, to decide the best approach.

For example if you wanted the frame at exactly 10.4 seconds and your video frame rate was 2 frames per second (as a simple, if unrealistic example), then the two nearest frames would be 10.0 and 10.5 seconds. There would be no exact frame at 10.4 seconds, although you could simply use the last frame displayed even though it is not the closest, or you could use the closet even though it is not being displayed yet.

It might be that you can meet your requirements by seeking to a particular frame rather than a particular time. There are frame accurate video players available, many of them with free trials that you can experiment with. For example:

- https://bitmovin.com/demos/frame-accurate-seeking
- http://demo.theoplayer.com/frame-accurate-seeking
- https://flowplayer.com/help/plugins/fas